# nVim disable error detection of coc plugin

Tags: neovim, disable, error-detection, coc.nvim

I use neovim with coc.nvim for auto-completion of code, but I don't like this error detection [I don't mean its bad], I only want to disable this grey like with red `>>` on the left of line numbers
(no problem with red line numbers)

[image]

---

How can I disable it,

- like a line of code Which can be added to .vimrc or .init.vim which will do the job
- that's what I want...

Answer (score 1):

put this in your `init.vim` file:

```
let b:coc_diagnostic_disable=1
```

if the error detection still present, edit your `coc-settings.json` file, it's located on the same location of your `init.vim` usually at `~/.config/nvim`, add this line:

```
{
  "diagnostic.enable": false
}
```

Comment: thats helpful, but, is there a way to only disable `>>`, without touching the red numbers as an error detection